# Event unique identifier

Tags: events, logs

The web3.js (1.0) docs [helpfully list](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events-return) the return values from a contract event subscription. I've noticed that there is an additional return value `id` that isn't listed there but is returned with the rest of the log data. An example of one is `log_6b4f6cdd`.

I'm looking for something that can help me uniquely identify a particular event even within a single tx or block. Is the `id` unique at least within a given contract?

Answer (score 1):

You can uniquely identify a particular event with the transactionHash combined with the logIndex.

I'm not sure what the id value is you're getting. Using a geth node, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to uniquely identify the event:

```
const eventId = { blockHash, transactionHash, logIndex }
```

Note that `blockHash` is required because there may be multiple events with the same topic in a single transaction.

Also, `blockHash` is required instead of `blockNumber` to make the code robust against chain reorgs (different `blockHash`, same `blockNumber`).

Comment: how will `blockHash` help in this situation of multiple events of same topic in same transaction? won't the block also be the same for them too?